# FirstOrDefault() returns first letter of the string

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I've a people object

```
        people.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Tim", Id = 1, LastName = "Corey" });
        people.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Sue", Id = 2, LastName = "Storm" });
        people.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Bilbo", Id = 3, LastName = "Baggins" });
```

I'm trying to query it by passing FirstName and LastName (Tim, Corey)

```
return people.Where(names => names.FirstName == FirstName && names.LastName == LastName).FirstOrDefault().FirstName;
```

This returns output as

```
"Tim"
```

When I added .FirstOrDefault() at the end. It brought strange output as

```
return people.Where(names => names.FirstName == FirstName && names.LastName == LastName).FirstOrDefault().FirstName.FirstOrDefault();

84 'T'
```

Could anyone explain how did the output produced.

> 84 'T'

Comment: String is `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: That's because when you add FirstOrDefault to yout FirstName which is of type string it will return first char from string

Comment: What else are you expecting as the result? You got the first name (Tim), what more did you need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling `.FirstOrDefault()` on `FirstName` which is a `string`. This will cause the `.FirstOrDefault()` to be called on the `IEnumerable<char>` implementation. This will result in returning the first or default character in that `string`.

The numeric value `84` is displaying the ASCII value for `T`.
http://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html

Comment: how 84 comes in that? It would be fine if i had got just T.

Comment: Since T is a `char`, it's showing the ASCII value for T, which is 84. ASCII codes: https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html

Comment: Thank you @Michael. I have added this to the answer

Answer (score 2):

Strings are arrays of characters, which can be enumerated by Linq.

FirstOrDefault returns the first item in the list, or null.
In this case, the first character in the array ['T', 'i', 'm'] is 'T'.

I think this is what you meant to write:

```
return people.First(names => names.FirstName == FirstName && names.LastName == LastName).FirstName;
```

Note: Using FirstOrDefault can return null, which would cause a NullReferenceException if there are no matches.

Alternatively:

```
var match = people.FirstOrDefault(n => n.FirstName == FirstName && n.LastName == LastName);
return (match == null) ? "" : match.FirstName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes - a `string` is essentially a `IEnumerable<char>` so when you call `FirstOrDefault()`, you're returning the first `char` in the `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Anyone able to explain to me how I'm wrong / why the downvote?